# Text not fine when applying CSS scale effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/d4hqjv3p/

I am trying to create text animate with css. when I use scale effect to text, it displaying blurry. But after finish the animation it will back to clear text.

Code :

```
<style>
    div {
        position: absolute;
        margin:100px;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        font-size:20px;
        font-family: arial;
        -webkit-transition: all .5s;
        -moz-transition: all .5s;
    }

    .scale {
        -webkit-transform: scale(3);
        -moz-transform: scale(3);
    }
</style>

<div>5</div>
<input type="button" value="Click to Animate" onClick="clickme()" />

Script :

function clickme() {
  $("div").addClass("scale");
}
```

Comment: Just checked and the solution to that question works for yours as well - http://jsfiddle.net/8751gjto/ :)

Comment: the browser must render the text after the scaling, works fine for me using chrome.

Comment: @kmoe that's (the solution provided on the dup qn) not working...

Comment: @C-linkNepal Maybe you're on Firefox? I missed out the `-moz-` prefixes from the question by mistake. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/8751gjto/1/

Comment: @kmoe: yes, this trick working nice.

Comment: @kmoe No, I'm still seeing blurry text...

Comment: @C-linkNepal Well then, providing more info like which browser, version etc you're using would be nice. Cuase when i checked it's fine in both safari and chrome.

Comment: I'm using firefox 31.